# Extract subimage in a image with borders wrapped around

Tags: c++, opencv

Say I have an image, and I'd like to extract a subimage assuming the original image is wrapped like a toroid.

My guess was doing something like

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Mat image = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    const int & rows = image.rows;
    const int & cols = image.cols;

    Rect roi = Rect(rows - 1, cols - 1, 51, 51);
    Mat subImage = image(roi);

    namedWindow("Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Window", subImage);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

But that didn't work. Is there anything you can suggest? maybe there's a function I'm missing that I can use?

If not what's the easiest way?

Comment: `Rect roi = Rect(-25, -25, 51, 51);` Why `-25`?

Comment: Because by default the first two parameters would specify the top left corner, since I want this to be the center of Rect I perform a subtraction. So that rect would be equivalent to one with center in `(0,0)` and width/height `51`.

Comment: doesnt that -25 throw an assertion fail to you? you never should use negative values, a Mat starts on the (0,0) point at top-left..

Comment: It throws an assertion, I was just trying to show what I was trying to achieve. I've changed the code a bit, hoping it's clearer.

Comment: The method you are using is ok. But it depends on you what part of the original image you want to take. If you want to get the center you can do roi=Rect(image.cols/2-25, image.rows/2-25, 50,50)

Comment: But what about the parts of the `Rect` that fall outside the original image? I want those parts to retain the part of the image that are in the opposite borders.

Comment: If your image is bigger than 50x50, the rect that i gave to you doesnt fall outside the original image. You cant take a part of an image that doesnt exists. Again, you should specify what you want.

Comment: @Yanet, I think I specified what I wanted in my last comment. My question is whether or not there's a built in function that achieves that.

Answer (score 0):

Negative values did not work as apparently the library in question does not support toroid-like image handling...

I now see two options for you:

- either extract (up to) four sub images and recombine them
- or do the extraction by hand

For the latter:

```
int cx = 0, cy = 0;
for(int y = lowerBoundY; y < upperBoundY; ++y)
{
    for(int x = lowerBoundX; x < upperBoundX; ++x)
    {
        subImage[cy][cx++] = image[(y + height) % height][(x + width) % width];
    }
    ++cy;
    cx = 0;
}
```

(Silently assuming you do not exceed the intervals `[-width;2*width)` and `[-height;2*height)`...)

Comment: I thought something like this was already implemented in the library though.

Answer (score 0):

Try openCV `copyMakeBorder`; it extracts subimages, offering several options for border treatment.